# Bot de Discord entra al canal pero no reproduce audio

Tags: javascript, discord.js

con todo el cambio al discord js estoy teniendo problemas para hacer que el bot entre y reproduzca un simple video en solo audio. Ya intente por un recurso local y usando un link a youtube, en ambos casos el bot entra al canal y no reproduce ningun sonido.

La opción del link la encontre en un post de la comunidad inglesa, francamente no se si funciona o no. En la documentación de Discord js solo encontre de la forma local, pero nada que me ayude.

Tengo instalados ffmpeg y configurado en variables del entorno. Con el resto de dependencias no tengo problemas tampoco.

Este es el código:

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const { createReadStream } = require('node:fs');
const { join } = require('node:path');
const { createAudioResource, StreamType } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const bot = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] })
const prefix = "-";
const token = '';

bot.on('ready', function(){
    console.log('Funcionando 100% Barrani');
});

bot.on('messageCreate', function(message) {
    if(message.author.equals(bot.user)) return;
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    var args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0].toLowerCase()){
        case 'alla':

                const channel = message.member.voice.channel

                if(!channel) return message.channel.send('Tenes que estar en el canal de voz BURRASO');

                //Creando el player
                const { createAudioPlayer } = require('@discordjs/voice');
                const player = createAudioPlayer();
                
                //Joineando el canal de voz, crea el VoiceConnection en connection
                const { joinVoiceChannel, createAudioResource } = require('@discordjs/voice');
                const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
                    channelId: channel.id,
                    guildId: channel.guild.id,
                    adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
                })
                
                const { VoiceConnectionStatus } = require('@discordjs/voice');

                connection.on(VoiceConnectionStatus.Ready, () => {
                console.log('The connection has entered the Ready state - ready to play audio!');
                });

                connection.subscribe(player) //Subscribe el player al VoiceConnection

                //Crear el resource para el player
                
                //Opcion de recurso local

                let resource = createAudioResource(join('C:\Users\Juan-\Desktop\MaslaBot\audio-resources\nobant.mp4'));

                //Opcion de url

                /*const url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ak5oJcXSnQw'
                const stream = ytdl(url, {filter: 'audioonly'});
                const resource = createAudioResource(stream)*/

                player.play(resource)


            break;

        default:
            message.channel.send('No se capo, al que programa no le pagan');
        break;
    }

});

bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude solucionar (por la forma de recurso local), faltaba agregar el "GUILD_VOICE_STATES" en los intents, tambien cambie el path del recurso a

const resource = createAudioResource('./audio-resources/nobant.mp4');

Encontré la solución en este post (que no se como no vi ayer):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70610280/discordjs-13-bot-not-playing-local-mp3-file